# Find the maximal $p$-divisible subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Q}^{\times},\cdot)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ has no maximal subgroup. So I think there is no maximal $p$-divisible subgroup. I don't have any idea... please...

Comment: It is possible that a group $G$ has no maximal subgroup, but there is a maximal subgroup satisfying an additional property. For example, suppose there was only one proper subgroup with that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maximal p-subgroup of (Q,x) is {-1,1}

pf) suppose that there exist maximal p-subgroup contains {1,-1},
 then there is elemnet $\frac{b}{a}$ in A where a,b in Z.
By definition of p-divisible,there element x such that $x^p =\frac{b}{a}$

where $a={{p_1}^{a_1}}{{p_2}^{a_2}}\ldots{{p_n}^{a_n}}, b={{p_1}^{b_1}}{{p_2}^{b_2}}\ldots{{p_n}^{b_n}}$.

1)if p don't divide $a_i$ or $b_i$ then x is irrational ===> contradiction.

2)if p divide both a_i and b_i, x is rational.
repeat same process above, sometimes there is x' which is irrational ==> contradiction.

So {-1, 1} is maximal p-divisible subgroup of (Q,x)